# NSMutableArray properties to populate UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a `UITableView` which I populate using a `NSMutableArray`. This `tableview` updates when scrolled down, which is brought about by adding more data to the `NSMutableArray`. The problem I am facing is that everytime I navigate away from this page to another and then back again, the `tableview` is set to the initial size of the array, no matter how many updates I do (meaning if I load ten objects each time, the tableview size reverts back to 10 even if the array size is 30, note: the array size never changes only the table content size does). I am starting to believe this has to do with the properties of the `NSMutableArray`. The gist of the code is this:

```
@interface FlowViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UITableView *flowTable;

    NSMutableArray *cellData;

}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *flowTable;

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *cellData;

- (void) getData;
- (void) storeData: (NSMutableArray*) arr; 

@end

@implementation FlowViewController

@synthesize cellData;

@synthesize flowTable;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.flowTable.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [self.flowTable setDataSource:self];
    [self.flowTable setDelegate:self];

    self.cellData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self getData];
}

- (void) storeData:(NSMutableArray *)arr
{
    for(NSDictionary *data in arr)
    {

        CellObject *det = [[CellObject alloc] init];

        // store details

        [self.cellData addObject: det];

    }

    [self.flowTable reloadData];
}

- (void) getData
{

    NSString *url = @"http://example.com/";

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest= [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                     timeoutInterval:10.0];

[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

flowConnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.cellData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FlowCell";

    MyFlowCell *cell = (MyFlowCell *)[self.flowTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FlowCell" owner:nil options:nil];
       // cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        for(id currentObject in nib)
        {

        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[MyFlowCell class]])

        {
            cell = (MyFlowCell *)currentObject;

        break;
    }
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}

CellObject *rowItem = [cellData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // set cell data

}

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewdidSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    self.current = indexPath.row;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"flowToAnotherSegue" sender:nil];

}


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"flowToAnotherSegue"])
    {
        NewViewController *iv =
            segue.destinationViewController;

    iv.current = self.current;
        iv.data = self.cellData;

    }

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma NSURLConnection Delegate Methods
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)_connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Receiving response: %@, status %d", [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response allHeaderFields],     [(NSHTTPURLResponse*) response statusCode]);
    receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)_connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Connection Failed: %@", error);   
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)_connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)_data {

       [receivedData appendData:_data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    // get the new NSMutableArray from receivedData

    [self storeData: newMutableArray];

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Deferred image loading (UIScrollViewDelegate)

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {

    if(Bottom reached) {

       // load more data

        [self getData];

        }

    }
}

@end
```

I hope that is not too much. Please tell me where I might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't find what is going wrong in my code, I have made a temporary fix. Like I said, the NSMutableArray cellData is not being changed, but the only thing that is changing is UITableView itself (I found this in my viewDidDisappear method). So I just did this to compensate for this

```
 - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.flowTable reloadData];

    [self.flowTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath: lastIndex atScrollPosition:0 animated: NO];

}
```

This returns the flowTable to the last selected cell. It isn't elegant, but it works. Please do keep posting your ideas. I really want to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 1):

Store the array in a shared class / singleton class.

As whenever you reload this page, `viewDidLoad` is called and your array is alloc+init is done again, setting it to its default value.

Comment: Make that array `static` is a bad way to go and almost always the wrong answer. The array does need to be defined as an ivar in a class that does persist.

Comment: Like I said, the size of the array stays the same, only the size of the UITableView changes. I've used NSLog statements to confirm this.

Comment: @Zaph, Do I need to set a property other than (nonatomic, retain) to the cellData ivar?

Comment: size of tableveiw never changes.... its in view and the changes are done in model (datasource).

Comment: Hmm. A singleton class is an interesting idea. Will try it out and let you know. :)

Answer (score 1):

Store the array in a shared class / singleton class. You can create your own shared class or you can use `appDelegate`.

- Declare a `NSMutableArray` property in appDelegate. `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *cellData;`
  and synthesize it.
- Use this array instead of your cellData array. 
  `AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` replace your `self.cellData` with `appDelegate.cellData`

Comment: The ivars in the appDelegate didn't work I'm afraid. :(

Answer (score 0):

if you delete the `self.cellData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` from view did load and create your own getter with a JIT approach:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)cellData
{
    if(!_cellData){
        _cellData = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return _cellData;
}
```

The contents of cellData will be preserved until FlowController is deallocated.

Comment: Hmm. This didn't work. For some reason the execution didn't get past the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is being recreated on viewDidLoad, you can just check if it already exists before allocating.

```
if (!self.cellData) {
    self.cellData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self getData];
}
```

Comment: If that is the case, then shouldn't my NSLog statement in my viewDidLoad method be called? Also, this change in the UITableView is happening before the viewDidDisappear method(Which I have not shown here). So, the change is happening in between the "tableViewdidSelectRowAtIndexPath" and "viewDidDisappear".

Comment: In that case, what are you doing with iv.data in your new view?

Comment: Using it in another scrollview. But I don't think that's affecting it in any way. I have another segue from a different button from a header field which doesn't pass any data. And this problem occurs even when I return from that view.

Comment: @Ram really think about: "Using it in another scrollview".

Comment: So you're saying that passing this array to another view will affect the ivar in my current view too?

Comment: If you are manipulating the array in your new view, then yes.

Comment: Then why is it happening in the other segue too? I tried commenting out the tableViewdidSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue methods. Then I opened the second segue (the one without any data transfer). And the problem still persists.

Comment: Then you must be doing something else to the array somewhere. Is there any more code you left out where you alter the content of cellData?

Comment: Nope. Nothing else. I'm still checking though. :(